# Annotations disappear after restart

Tags: qgis, annotation

When adding text annotations to QGIS they work well, but when I shut the program down and restart I cannot get them to reappear. They still exist in Annotations panel, and they appear in layout view, but for the life of me I cannot get them to appear again in the GIS view. I tried linking them to a layer in the hope that this would save them, but no luck. I can toggle the view for annotations that I have created during the session, but as soon as I save, close, and reopen they will not render on the screen.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what version are you using that is giving you this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Two options mate::

1. CRTL + T, toggles on off annotations
2. Annotation Panel. You can individually select annotations for toggling. (View tab, panels --> Annotations)